# Define table headers in Grails domain class for view generation

Tags: templates, grails, scaffolding

I want to be able to define view table headers in domain classes. I thought about creating a transient property called inTable and then iterate through its values in scaffolding template. Here is a transient property:

```
List inTable=['cardId','fullName','dateOfBirth','sex','bloodGroup','civilStatus','status']
```

Now How can I get inTable values inside my scaffolding template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make it a static field of your domain class.
2. Take a look at the way regular scaffolding iterates the class properties. (run [`grails install-templates`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) if you haven't yet)
3. Access `domainClass.getClazz().inTable`.

Comment: Can I access list methods of inTable like contains?like domainClass.inTable.contains("")?

Comment: Absolutely. `domainClass` is a class reference, `.inTable` is a static field - no other magic here.

Comment: I tried your solution and got the following exception: Error executing script GenerateViews: No such property: inTable for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass

Comment: I guess this is because I defined inTable as transient? Is there a workaround to solve this as I don't want to persist this value in database.

Comment: Yes, `transient` is not static. Make it `static`, it won't be persisted - only instance fields are persisted.

Comment: Now my bad, I missed `domainClass.getClazz()` piece. Updated. `DefaultGrailsDomainClass' is a sort of "artifact descriptor" in Grails, where artifact types are like: controllers, domain classes, taglib and so on.